# What is the correct preposition? "Das Problem liegt ... in / an / bei / mit"

Tags: preposition

What is the correct preposition to use in the following structure:

> Das Problem liegt **in / an / bei / mit** X

> Das Problem liegt **darin / daran / dabei / damit**, dass X...

Comment: For the first sentence I can imagine different prepositions depending on the context. I suggest to [edit] your question and add more context or examples for X in German or English.

Comment: @Bodo, this is a general question not related to a specific situation. There is nothing to edit. Please, see a proper answer below.

Comment: My comment was not intended as an answer but a comment asking for clarification. Of course it would be possible to add examples of what you want to say. Or even adding the information that you don't know in which context you want to use this phrase or that you want to know all possible contexts anyone can think of. IMHO there are even other situations/meanings not covered by [Hubert Schölnast's answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/73194/43666).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends.

It could be **in:**

> Tom: Wir haben ein Problem. (We have a problem.)
> Angelica: Was für ein Problem? (What kind of problem?)
> Tom: Das Problem liegt **in** der großen Truhe. (The problem lies **in** the big chest.)
> Angelika öffnet die Truhe und findet darin die Leiche von Dr. Steiner. (Angelica opens the chest and finds the body of Dr. Steiner inside.)

Similar examples can be constructed for every local preposition (*auf, unter, über, hinter, außerhalb von, ...*) as long as the problem can have a spatial location.

---

It could be **an:**

> Willst du damit sagen, es liegt an mir? Glaubst du wirklich, das Problem liegt **an** mir? Wer hat denn unser ganzes Geld ausgegeben? Wer hat das Auto zu Schrott gefahren? War ich das etwa? Nein, das warst alles du! Das Problem liegt nicht **an** mir. Es liegt ganz allein nur an dir!
>
> Are you saying it's because of me? Do you really think the problem is about me? Who spent all our money? Who totaled the car? Was it me? No, it was all you! The problem is not about me. It's all because of you!

It also could be **bei.** In the example using *an* you can replace any bold *an* with *bei* and you also get perfectly correct sentences that mean exactly the same.

---

But *mit* is a wrong preposition for problems and the verb *liegen*.

But still something like this can happen:

> Das Problem liegt **mit** an der Drosselklappe, aber die eigentliche Ursache sind die Zündkerzen.
> The problem is **also** with the throttle, but the real cause is the spark plugs.

But here the word **mit** is not a preposition. The preposition is the next word: *an*, and we discussed *an* in the section before.

The word *mit* is here an adverb. You often find *mit* as prefix of other German words: Mitarbeiter = co-worker (employee), Mitbewohner = co-resident (roommate), Mitfahrer = co-driver (passenger) and when ever it is used it describes something that happens *with* (in the sense of: *in addition to*) something else. And when *mit* is used as standalone adverb, it has the same meaning. So, in this example, the word *mit* expresses, that the throttle is an additional problem. The word *mit* in this construction is not a preposition that belongs to *»Problem liegt«* in the same way as the words *in, an* and *bei* in the examples above.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to write such an elaborate answer! It helped me soooooo much in lerning German. I saw "Problem liegt" with different prepositions before and found it consufing. Now I see the logic!

Comment: "Das Problem liegt in der großen Truhe." is actually a linguistic joke. Usually *das Problem liegt in* is used with a cause, not a location: "Das Problem liegt in deiner Faulheit." (The Problem is that you are lazy.) When someone says "Das Problem liegt in der Truhe", the expectation is that the chest or freezer is the problem, not that it is something lying inside it.